# Adding new User to contact list of existing users in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add New user to contact list of existing users contact list. Whenever child(new user) is added to users list, it has its own contact list, now every user in his contact list needs to be updated with the contact details of new user.

User structure:
[image]

Contact Structure:
[image]

I have written below cloud function, which is working-

```
 var functions = require('firebase-functions');

 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.newUserAdd = functions.database.ref('users/{uid}').onWrite(event => {

  const userObj = event.data.val();
  const userKey = event.data.key;
  console.log("New user added: " + userKey + " " + userObj.display_name);
  const userRef = admin.database().ref('/users');

  return event.data.child('contacts').forEach(function(data1){
    console.log("Updating " + data1.key + " adding contact: " + userKey);
    userRef.child(data1.key).child('contacts').child(userKey).set({display_name:userObj.display_name,type:userObj.type});
  });
});
```

But there way too many invocations which happens whenever any user's data is updated. Is there any way to invoke function only if new user is added or "display_name" or "type" of any user is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen for the trap of nesting different data types under a common root. In the Firebase Database it is recommended to keep each type of data under its own part of the tree.

In your case, there are two type of data:

- the simple properties of a user
- the related contacts of a user

It's idiomatic to model these as two separate top-level nodes:

```
users
  $uid
    displayName: ""
    type: ""
contacts
  $uid
    $contactUid: true
```

You'll note that both collections use `$uid` as their key. This means that you can easily look up either the profile of a user or the contacts of that user once you know their UID.

With this structure it is also simple to only trigger when the user's profile changes. Just register your function to only trigger on changes under `/users`:

```
exports.newUserAdd = functions.database.ref('users/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
  if (!event.data.previous.exists() && event.data.exists()) {
```

You'll note that I also added a condition that ensures the code only runs when the user record is first written.

Comment: `exports.newUserAdd = functions.database.ref('users/{uid}').onWrite` <-- Does this line mean that function will be invoked whenever child is added/modified or just added?

Comment: It's invoked on every write. That's why the next line checks whether it's a new node.

Comment: The reason I ask is there are way too many invocations which exhausts my daily quota. Is there any way to invoke function only when child is added  and not when there is any write operation?

Comment: There is no such precondition filtering at the moment, but we know it is a common feature request.